# Need to separate Kleene star definition into two cases

Tags: logic, computer-science

The definition of the Kleene star is separated into two cases [[1](http://planetmath.org/kleenestar)] [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)]:

> If $\Sigma$ is an alphabet (a set of symbols), then the Kleene star of
>   $\Sigma$, denoted $\Sigma^*$, is the set of all strings of finite
>   length consisting of symbols in $\Sigma$, including the empty string
>   $\lambda$.
>
> If $S$ is a set of strings, then the Kleene star of $S$, denoted
>   $S^*$, is the smallest superset of $S$ that contains $\lambda$ and is
>   closed under the string concatenation operation.  That is, $S^*$ is
>   the set of all strings that can be generated by concatenating zero or
>   more strings in $S$.

Question: why do we separate the definition into two distinct cases? How is one definition different than the other?

Comment: It's subtle. Basically the first definition, suitably formalized, tells you what a string is, and you need to know what strings are for the second definition to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both definitions are a special instance of a more general definition. Given a subset $S$ of a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) $M$, $S^*$ denotes the submonoid of $M$ generated by $S$.
If $S$ is a set of words, i.e. a subset of the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on $A$, you recover your second definition. Moreover, if $S = A$, then $S^*$ is the free monoid on $A$, which justifies the first notation: the set of all words on the alphabet $A$ is denoted $A^*$.